# Mysql SELECT all rows where char exists in value but not the last one

Tags: mysql

I need a SELECT query in MYSQL that will retrieve all rows in one table witch field values contain "?" char with one condition: the char is not the last character

Example:

```
ID Field
1  123??see
2  12?
3  45??78??
```

Returning rows would then be those from ID 1 and 3 that match the condition given

The only statement I have is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Field LIKE '%?%'
```

But, the MySQL query does not solve my problem..

Answer (score 4):

The LIKE expressions also support a wildcard "`_`" which matches exactly one character.

So you can write an expression like the example below, and know that your "?" will not be the last character in the string. There must be at least one more character.

```
WHERE intrebare LIKE '%?_%'
```

---

Re comment from @JohnRuddell,

Yes, that's true, this will match the string "??" because a "?" exists in a position that is not the last character.

It depends whether the OP means for that to be a match or not. The OP says the string "45??78??" is a match, but it's not clear if they would intend that "4578??" to be a match.

An alternative is to use a regular expression, but this is a little more tricky because you have to escape a literal "?", so it won't be interpreted as a regexp metacharacter. Then also escape the escape character.

```
WHERE intrebare REGEXP '\\?[^?]'
```

Comment: this wont work if there are two questionmarks at the end of a string though right?

Comment: see [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05cd20/1) it will return a row that ends in a question mark in some cases

Answer (score 2):

you can just add an additional where where the last character is not a ?

```
SELECT *
FROM intrebari
WHERE intrebare LIKE '%?%' AND intrebare NOT LIKE '%?'
```

you could also do it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM intrebari
WHERE intrebare LIKE '%?%' AND RIGHT(intrebare,1) <> '?'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05cd20/2)

Comment: What about row 3 that the OP shows? That should be a match.

Comment: @BillKarwin I am not sure.. The OP has contradicting information in his question... first thing says that the last character can't be a ? but then says rows 1 and 3 and row 3 has a questionmark at the end... confusing. regardless i already +1'd your answer its a good answer :)

Comment: Row 3 passes the condition as it is stated. The string has a "?" where it is not the last character. In fact, it has three "?" characters in positions that are not the last character. That's not a contradiction. You are assuming that a series of "?" characters that end at the last position is not a match, but the OP didn't say that.

Comment: @BillKarwin well not exactly... my confusion was when the OP said that it had to contain a ? and that it couldn't be at the end... I was thinking the OP ONLY wanted rows where there was no ? at the end whether or not there was one in the middle of the string.

Comment: But they said that row 3 is a match, even though it has a ? at the end.